# Why does operator associativity work differently for Scala 3 extension methods and regular methods?

Tags: scala, scala-3

When I manually converted Scala 2 code to Scala 3, operator precedence for my DSL changed, and it took me a long time to debug and fix. It seems the handling of `:` is different:

```scala
      extension (i1: Int) def ~>:(i2: Int) = i1 < i2
      extension (i1: Int) def ~>(i2: Int) = i1 < i2

      class Wrap(val i: Int):
        def ~>:(w: Wrap) = i ~>: w.i
        def ~>(w: Wrap) = i ~> w.i

      // `Wrap` preserves `~>`
      println(1 ~> 2) // true
      println(Wrap(1) ~> Wrap(2)) // true

      // `Wrap` does not preserve `~>:`
      println(1 ~>: 2) // true
      println(Wrap(1) ~>: Wrap(2)) // false
```

My mental model was:

- For methods ending in `:`, the reciever is the thing on the right
- extension methods are just methods: it's as if the method is added to the class

My mental model seems to be wrong. What's the right way of explaining what's happening?

Links would help, I checked the Scala 3 docs and didn't find anything about how custom operators associate.

### Update

I tried adding `infix` keyword before `def`, but it doesn't change what is printed in this example.

Comment: I have the impression that there is indeed a problem, but your specific example is very confusing, because of all the integers on both sides, and comparisons and left-right, and two nesting levels and what not. Here is an example that simply produces a compilation error: `class A(val i: Int) { infix def >>:(s: String) = s + ">>:" + i };
  extension (h: A) { infix def >+:(s: String) = s + ">+:" + h.i };
  println("x" >>: A(42));
  println("y" >+: A(58));`, without any arithmetic and less-than-greater-than confusions.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin  "simple" can be subjective - thank you for this additional example. Also - I'm not saying Scala is doing the wrong thing, just that I need help forming a coherent mental model of what it's doing and a link to a good reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mental model just needs some tweaking.

Recall that the infix `x op y` de-sugars to `x.op(y)`, except when the op ends with a colon, then it's `y.op:(x)`. This holds true whether the `op()` method is native to the instance parameter or an added extension, which, in Scala-2, is handled by an intermediate implicit class.

```
implicit class IntermediateClass(instance: Int) {
  def op(arg: Int) = ???
}
```

A Scala-3 `extension`, on the other hand, is just a method that receives two curried arguments. So the infix invocation `leftOfOp op rightOfOp` will always be handled as such:

```
extension (leftOfOp: Int)
  def op(rightOfOp: Int) = ???
```

And it's the same whether `op` has a trailing `:` or not. But, while the code at the definition site remains consistent in this manner, the associativity at the call site is as you would expect.

```
extension (left: String)
  def @:(right: String):String = s"$left.@:($right)"
  def @@(right: String):String = s"$left.@@($right)"

"TOP" @: "MID" @: "END"  //"TOP.@:(MID.@:(END))"
"top" @@ "mid" @@ "end"  //"top.@@(mid).@@(end)"
```

More details can be found [here](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html#operators) and [here](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/right-associative-extension-methods.html).