# Why do right associative extension methods have the opposite target from normal methods?

Tags: scala, extension-methods, scala-3, associativity

I've read all of the [reference docs](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html) and [expanded explanation](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/right-associative-extension-methods.html), and have seen the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149684/why-does-operator-associativity-work-differently-for-scala-3-extension-methods-a).

While I understand the need to re-swap the operands for the curried arguments on the extension method, there is still a practical behavior difference I don't understand. From the perspective of the caller, identical syntax results in confusingly divergent behavior.

Take this trivial example:

```
class S (s: String):
  def ?:(i: I): String = "On S"

class I(i: Int):
  def ?:(s: S): String = "On I"

extension (s1: S)
  def +:(i1: I): String = "On S"

extension (i1: I)
  def +:(s1: S): String = "On I"
```

In the extension methods, I'm extending (or adding a method to) the target type.  For example, the first one adds to `S`.  So I'd expect the `+:` there to behave identically to the `?:` on S above.  But in fact it is opposite:

```
S("foo") ?: I(1) // I is the target and it returns "On I"
S("foo") +: I(1) // S is the target and it returns "On S"
```

Is this a bug?  Or is Scala 3 moving towards a future where the behavior of the class method is wrong here?  Basically... how can both of these be correct and unambiguous for newcomers to the language.

Incidentally, this isn't an issue with Scala 2 syntax:

```
implicit class S1(s: S):
  def %:(i: I): String = "On S"

implicit class I1(i: I):
  def %:(s: S): String = "On I"

S("foo") ?: I(1) // I is the target and it returns "On I"
S("foo") %: I(1) // I is the target and it returns "On I"
```

To be clear, I'm not looking for the explanation of the implementation of extension methods that has been provided at the links I referenced above. I understand that aspect.

I'm also not confused about the parenthetical ordering of chained operations with left and right associative methods.

What I don't understand is, from a language design perspective, how can both `S("foo") ?: I(1)` and `S("foo") +: I(1)` (as given above) both be considered "correct"?  They are syntactically identical yet are opposites of each other with regard to determining target and operand.

Comment: I came here to write an answer and clear this up. But as I read through the documents you linked, I find myself as confused as you are. Great question, and I hope someone comes along and answers it, for both of our sakes.

Comment: Sounds like a bug IMHO.

Comment: The best that I can come up with is that this is a bug that stems from an older proposed extension syntax which would have had right-associative operators defined like:
`def (rhs: RType) ?: (lhs: LType): Out = ...`
or similar.  Basically, declare it the same way it is used.  That would be fine and makes sense, but with the change in extension syntax, I wonder if this proposal got munged into accidentally swapping the target.

I'll give it some time to see if someone closer to this can point out something I've missed.  If not, I guess I'll figure out where/how to report it.

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues is a good place to report it.

Comment: [Reported](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/18494)

Comment: For those keeping an eye on such things, my bug report was closed as working as designed.  I have followed up asking for clarity around how the _documented_ behavior can be considered in alignment with the _actual_ behavior and for guidance around how I can provide feedback on language design issues if this isn't a bug.